# SwingWorker synchronized method queue blocking or what?

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, blocking, swingworker

Theoretical question.  If I have two SwingWorkers and an outputObject with method

```
public void synchronized outputToPane(String output)
```

If each SwingWorker has a loop in it as shown:

```
//SwingWorker1
while(true) { 
     outputObject.outputToPane("garbage");
}
//SwingWorker2
Integer i=0;
while(true) {
     outputObject.outputToPane(i.toString());
     i++;
}
```

How would those interact?  does the outputToPane method receive an argument from one thread and block the other one until it finishes with the first, or does it build a queue of tasks that will execute in the order received, or some other option?

The reason I ask:
I have two threads that will be doing some heavy number crunching, one with a non-pausable data stream and the other from a file.  I would like them both to output to a central messaging area when they hit certain milestones;  however, I CANNOT risk the data stream getting blocked while it waits for the other thread to finish with the output.  I will risk losing data then.

Comment: Try http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`synchronized` only guarantees mutual exclusion. Is not *fair*, which in practice means that your workers might alternate quite nicely, or the first one might get precedence and block the second one completely until finished, or anything between.

See [Reentrantlock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) docs for more about fairness. Maybe you could consider using it instead of `synchronized`. Probably even better alternative would be using a [Queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html).

Comment: That makes sense.  I guess I should move to some sort of event system , make use of publish/process with a non-synchronized method, or have a second output area as nevero states then?

Comment: Ah yes.  Okay, use a queue of 'events', and have each method simply push one onto the stack, and then I can have another output worker thread to process them as they come, blocking when the queue is empty?

Comment: Exactly. If you do it right, multiple output areas don't increase safety. They all would have to be updated from the EDT anyway.

Comment: If you don't mind the results being interleaved, just do the screen updates in each worker's `process()`; the [`EventQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html) offers "the same order as they are enqueued."

Comment: So, publish/process already pulls off the functionality I am looking for.  Thank you Trashgod

Comment: @Sheriff: Yes, each `publish()` (effectively) enqueues another `Runnable` on the EDT. In the worst case, some `chunks` may be coalesced.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to have two output object in your messaging area. Because if one thread starts to modify the output answer then the other one will have to wait for it to finish. Even if you can optimize it to make it fast enough, the actual display of info would make your threads slow each others down over time.

Although you might try to synchronize them, the result might not always be 100% safe